# Which experiment clearly shows us that Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is ontological and not epistemological?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

I have heard that the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle(HUP) is not because of our limitations in measuring and the apparatus used but instead because of the very way things are

I searched online in vain, I just want to one experimental or the logical proof behind this.

Comment: Do any of the proofs in you QM books involve a description of equipment?  If no, then surely those proofs are logical and show the result have nothing to do with experimental errors.

Answer (score 7):

The heisenberg uncertainty is tied up with the wave equations which describe and predict measurements in the microcosm of particles atoms and nuclei. The HUP is directrly connected to the commutation rules of the operators in quantum mechanics.

$$[x,p]=i\frac h {2\pi}$$

where x,p are operators acting on the wavefunction quantum mechanical solutions.

[This link is useful](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys580/fa2013/uncertainty.pdf)

> While we need this operator equation to derive a concrete result, the general idea is present in *any system where there are plane waves.*  A physically realizable wave is always in the form of a wave packet
>   which is finite in extent. A wave packet is built up
>   by superposing waves with definite wave number. By simple Fourier analysis, a highly localized packet will require a wide spread of wave vectors, whereas a packet with a large spacial extent can be composed of wave numbers quite close to a specific value.

Italics mine

For a classical electromagnetic wave for example :

[image: wavepacket]

Once one understands that real particles cannot be modeled/represented by a simple plane wave because it would be extended from -infinity to +infinity, wavepackets are necessary in the quantum mechanical model of the world, to bound the probable location where it  can be measured.

It is only the use of $\frac h{2\pi}$   that is specific to quantum mechanical wave packets, and the experimental verification of the need for  h is in all quantum mechanical  measurements from spectra to decays.

Comment: as a btw, I remember being quite surprised to find the uncertainty  connected with wavelength and frequency in classical electromagnetism, back in 1963 or so, I think in Stratton,.

Comment: I think in this answer you have assumed that Copenhagen is true, am I right?

Comment: What's your opinion on this ??https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402639/mbnm-measuringbynotmeasuring-thought-experiment-is-this-wrong-if-so-how

Comment: Yes, C,but the other interpretations also have to agree on the data, there would be different mathematical formulations, but the end result, as to wave packet, is one way.

Comment: I am not good with thought experiments. After all you already have an electron trapped in the hydrogen atom. The solution gives a fixed energy, and time infinity with the HUP (dEdt) , it is stable; unless there is interaction. Then the wavepacket solutions have to be used,