# Wave packet construction in Heisenberg's The Physical Principles of the Quantum Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, waves, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am trying to understand Heisenberg's development of a wave packet.  This is the context:

[image]

This is the statement confusing me (following eq #1):

> "Outside the boundary the component plane waves must cancel by interference; this is possible if, and only if, the set of component waves contains some for which at least n+1 waves fall in the critical range."

Excerpt From: "The Physical Principles of the Quantum Theory" by Werner Heisenberg. Scribd. This material may be protected by copyright. Read this book on Scribd: https://www.scribd.com/book/271560462

**Question: Should the second occurrence of the word "waves" in the following be understood to mean 'complete cycles'?**

> "the set of component waves contains some for which at least n+1 **waves** fall in the critical range."

Comment: maybe my answer here is relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402793/

Comment: I am specifically asking about the statement in Heisenberg's book.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation I suggested is the only reasonable understanding of the statement.  The alternative is that $n+1$ is the number of component waves in the sum producing the wave-packet.